# Why Linux has "bridge" link type, and not a "switch"

Tags: networking, ip, bridge

In Linux, we can have a virtual bridge device. It is used i.e. by Docker, which creates a default "docker0" bridge.
Since in networking bridge is a similar device to a switch (and switch is actually superior and used nowadays instead of bridges), I wonder, why is the link type called "bridge", and not "switch"?

Comment: Hmm, that question does not really give a clear answer. From what I know hub < bridge < switch. The answer in the linked post hints that Linux bridge is more like a switch (or even better). I guess the "bridge" term can also generally mean a device that acts like a hub/bridge/switch, and this is why this name is being used.

Comment: Switches are bridges. And what ever the distinction between a (multiport) bridge and a switch has originally been seems a thing of the past. The terminology just has a life of its own. E.g. if you buy an enterprise _switch_, and start configuring Spanning Tree, you'll see mentions of the _bridge_ priority, and also a few switches support an SNMP MIB called Q-BRIDGE-MIB from [RFC 4363](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4363). If you look at the RFC, it basically equates bridges to switches, and while it tries to be consistent, it manages to slip the other term in once, too.

Comment: Scanning [some Q:s on networkengineering.SE](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/search?q=bridge+switch), the opinion seems to be that the phrase "switch" [came up as a marketing term](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/q/43668/25437) for multi-port bridges (which pretty much means the term would be devoid of an accurate technical meaning...), but also that it was related to the [increased number of ports](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/q/456/25437) and partly about doing stuff on dedicated hardware as opposed to software.